# DataMapper problems on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, datamapper

I am trying to deploy a simple app to Heroku (Sinatra and using DataMapper for the ORM), and I am getting these errors whenever I try to submit my form:

```
2011-08-03T22:52:05+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pure-mist-880.heroku.com/public/css/raffler.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=18
2011-08-03T22:52:06+00:00 heroku[nginx]: GET /public/css/raffler.css HTTP/1.1 | 12.185.40.153 | 340 | http | 404
2011-08-03T22:52:15+00:00 app[web.1]: DataObjects::SyntaxError - ser=jjimxarsyb&password=2QbwU-iBQ6IckNTQqQ05&host=ec2-107-20-254-131.compute-1.amazonaws.com&port=&path=/jjimxarsyb&query=&fragment=&adapter=postgres:
2011-08-03T22:52:15+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/.gems/gems/dm-do-adapter-1.1.0/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb:114:in `execute_non_

...
2011-08-03T22:52:16+00:00 heroku[nginx]: POST / HTTP/1.1 | 12.185.40.153 | 297 | http | 500
```

The setup line I'm currently using is (taken from the Heroku DevCenter):

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || 'sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/entries.db')
```

EDIT:

I added dm-do-adapter to my .gems file and that resolved that issue. Now, when I submit my form, I'm still presented with "Internal Server Error" in the browser, and my logs only show:

```
2011-08-04T01:19:30+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pure-mist-880.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=54ms status=200 bytes=919
2011-08-04T01:19:30+00:00 heroku[nginx]: GET / HTTP/1.1 | 71.199.2.204 | 1218 | http | 200
2011-08-04T01:19:31+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pure-mist-880.heroku.com/public/css/raffler.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=18
2011-08-04T01:19:36+00:00 heroku[router]: POST pure-mist-880.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=35ms status=500 bytes=30
```

I don't know why my .css file isn't loading, and why it's failing when I submit my form.

If you need more code snippets, let me know. Thank you in advance for any ideas.

Comment: I'm not sure but the `public` in `pure-mist-880.heroku.com/public/css/raffler.css` shouldn't be there since the folder gets mapped to `/` iirc. Maybe you have a wrong path somewhere? In your template perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"public" should not be apart of your routes anywhere.

From the sintra.rb [intro documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro):

> Note that the public directory name is not included in the URL. A file `./public/css/style.css` is made available as `example.com/css/style.css`.

If you have your static assets placed elsewhere you can define it yourself as well:

```
set :public, File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/static'
```

Concerning the last line, do you have a `post` route for the root? Something like:

```
post '/' do
  #form processing using params[:input_name]
end
```

Is this application working in a local dev environment?

Comment: Actually, that set :public line is exactly what it took to get things working correctly. I just changed '/static' to '/public' and everything worked as it should. I was running on a local machine in production (using Thin) to test what it would look like when I upload it to Heroku. Thanks for your answer; it reminded me that I hadn't updated my findings in the past couple of days. =]

Comment: In classic sinatra apps (no Sinatra::Base subclassing) it assumes 'public' is the static assets folder. When you write a modern Sinatra application, you have to specify the where the static assets exist with the class using that `set :public` line. :) cheers!